# Printing Excel file

Tags: c#, wpf

```
          xlWorkSheet.PrintOut();
```

This should work but according to the documentation, this is going to use the printer by default. Is it possible to give the user the ability to choose a printer like this:

[image]

In WinForms, I believe It's possible to achieve such a thing by using a PrintDialog like this:

```
var pd = new PrintDialog();
var settings = pd.PrinterSettings;
var name = settings.PrinterName
```

What's the equivalent for that in WPF? I don't see `PrinterSettings/PrinterName`

**EDIT (more details):**

I'm creating an excel file using Interop. The first code I posted will print the file using the default printer. I want from the user to be able to choose a printer. I realize there is `ActivePrinter` option but I will have to know the name of the printer in this case I believe.

What I want to do is make a printer dialog and get the Selected printer name and set it to `ActivePrinter`

Comment: There's no built-in Excel support in WPF, much less a `PrintOut()` method. Shouldn't you check the documentation of *that* class? Even in WinForms you *can't* change printer settings if that other class won't let you

Comment: I'm using Interop.

Comment: Have you tried something like [this](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/Document-Operation/How-to-Print-Excel-File-in-WPF.html)? Literally the first search result.

Comment: @Zkai in which case you can't use the `PrintDialog()` class even in WinForms. I suggest you post a question that explains what you actually want to do - You are using Excel Interop and want to change the print settings.

Comment: @Zkai btw the answer should be easy to find, probably in the docs of the `PrintOut()` method itself or a reference. You are looking for a way to use Excel's own print settings

Comment: @JurgenCamilleri that's about a specific library, it's not usable as a generic solution. Besides, the OP uses Interop

Comment: @JurgenCamilleri I'm creating the file which takes time, so I don't want to take more time to load it again.

Comment: @JurgenCamilleri on the other hand, finding out how to change print settings using Excel Interop should be rather easy

Comment: @zkai please edit your question or post a new one with the *relevant* information. You are *not* printing from WPF, you are printing using Excel itself. The answer is to use Excel's own methods. The docs for [Printout() itself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/sheets-printout-method-excel) show that you can select the active printer. Are you trying to change the printer? Change the settings? Use your own settings dialog or are you OK with Excel's?

Comment: @zkai check [Worksheet.PageSetup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheet-pagesetup-property-excel) too. Excel's API is the same no matter the language, which means you can use VBA docs as easily as C# docs. It also means you can *record a VBA macro* with the steps you want to perform, check the generated code and repeat the same steps in your code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos added the details necessary